# How do I get the Session Object in Spring?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am relatively new to [Spring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spring_Framework) and Spring security.

I was attempting to write a program where I needed to authenticate a user at the server end using Spring security,

I came up with the following:

```
public class CustomAuthenticationProvider extends AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider{
    @Override
    protected void additionalAuthenticationChecks(UserDetails userDetails, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken)
                    throws AuthenticationException
    {
        System.out.println("Method invoked : additionalAuthenticationChecks isAuthenticated ? :"+usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.isAuthenticated());
    }

    @Override
    protected UserDetails retrieveUser(String username,UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authentication) throws AuthenticationException 
    {
        System.out.println("Method invoked : retrieveUser");
        //so far so good, i can authenticate user here, and throw exception if not authenticated!!
        //THIS IS WHERE I WANT TO ACCESS SESSION OBJECT
    }
}
```

My usecase is that when a user is authenticated, I need to place an attribute like:

```
session.setAttribute("userObject", myUserObject);
```

myUserObject is an object of some class that I can access throughout my server code across multiple user requests.

Answer (score 161, accepted):

Your friend here is [`org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextHolder`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/web/context/request/RequestContextHolder.html)

```
// example usage
public static HttpSession session() {
    ServletRequestAttributes attr = (ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes();
    return attr.getRequest().getSession(true); // true == allow create
}
```

This will be populated by the standard spring mvc dispatch servlet, but if you are using a different web framework you have add `org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter` as a filter in your `web.xml` to manage the holder.

**EDIT**: just as a side issue what are you actually trying to do, I'm not sure you should need access to the `HttpSession` in the `retieveUser` method of a `UserDetailsService`. Spring security will put the UserDetails object in the session for you any how. It can be retrieved by accessing the `SecurityContextHolder`:

```
public static UserDetails currentUserDetails(){
    SecurityContext securityContext = SecurityContextHolder.getContext();
    Authentication authentication = securityContext.getAuthentication();
    if (authentication != null) {
        Object principal = authentication.getPrincipal();
        return principal instanceof UserDetails ? (UserDetails) principal : null;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: @first point:
I tried using RequestContextHolder, it gave me an error:
No thread-bound request found:Are you referring to  ...  use RequestContextListener or RequestContextFilter to expose the current request.
I didnt try filters i guess, will try that and let u know if it works.

@second point: 
actually its a custom object hence i didnt prefer UserDetails

if possible do see my other question on similar topic:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1629273/is-it-possible-to-send-more-data-in-form-based-authentication-in-spring

Comment: if you are not using the dispatch servlet you need to configure: RequestContextFilter

Comment: 1. attr.getSession(true);  >> is protected method and is not accessible in CustomAuthenticationProvider 
    
2. this is wht i did in my web.xml:
<filter>
  <filter-name>requestContextFilter</filter-name>
  <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter</filter-class>
 </filter>
 <filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>requestContextFilter</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
 </filter-mapping>

still the same error occurs.

Comment: sorry my mistake... adapted the code from my own project which uses getRequest, the answer is updated

Comment: ok, but my point 2 is still prevalent:
No thread-bound request found: Are you referring to request attributes outside of an actual web request, or processing a request outside of the originally receiving thread? If you are actually operating within a web request and still receive this message, your code is probably running outside of DispatcherServlet/DispatcherPortlet: In this case, use RequestContextListener or RequestContextFilter to expose the current request.

Comment: Is this wrong ?



<filter>
  <filter-name>requestContextFilter</filter-name>
  <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter</filter-class>
 </filter>
 <filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>requestContextFilter</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
 </filter-mapping>

Comment: nope that looks about right... try stopping your code in a debugger and checking that RequestContextFilter is in the call stack

Comment: thanks mate, it worked, turns out that i had placed this after the DelegatingFilterProxy filter in web.xml

I didnt know that the order of filters did matter here.

a new lesson learnt, thanks for the effort.

Comment: I found that **RequestContextFilter** didn't work for me whereas **RequestContextListener** did...
`<listener><listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class></listener>`

Comment: Just make sure to add RequestContextListener in your web.xml    <listener>
 <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class> 
   </listener> in case of using RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes();

Comment: Thumbs up to both your solutions. An enhancement to the `currentUserDetails` could be made to instead return the username which could also be an `Authentication` object or a string of the username itself, this could be tested and return just the username instead of the whole `UserDetails` making it a little more universal.

Comment: It's a bug prone solution.

Answer (score 37):

Since you're using Spring, stick with Spring, don't hack it yourself like the other post posits.

The [Spring manual](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/technical-overview.html) says:

> You shouldn't interact directly with the HttpSession for security
>   purposes. There is simply no justification for doing so - always use
>   the SecurityContextHolder instead.

The suggested best practice for accessing the session is:

```
Object principal = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();

if (principal instanceof UserDetails) {
  String username = ((UserDetails)principal).getUsername();
} else {
  String username = principal.toString();
}
```

The key here is that Spring and Spring Security do all sorts of great stuff for you like Session Fixation Prevention. These things assume that you're using the Spring framework as it was designed to be used. So, in your servlet, make it context aware and access the session like the above example.

If you just need to stash some data in the session scope, try creating some session scoped bean like [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10034993/spring-store-object-in-session) and let autowire do its magic. :)

Answer (score 6):

i made my own utils. it is handy. :)

```
package samples.utils;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Locale;

import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;
import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationEventPublisher;
import org.springframework.context.MessageSource;
import org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionService;
import org.springframework.core.io.ResourceLoader;
import org.springframework.core.io.support.ResourcePatternResolver;
import org.springframework.ui.context.Theme;
import org.springframework.util.ClassUtils;
import org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextHolder;
import org.springframework.web.context.request.ServletRequestAttributes;
import org.springframework.web.context.support.WebApplicationContextUtils;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.LocaleResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ThemeResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.support.RequestContextUtils;


/**
 * SpringMVC通用工具
 * 
 * @author 应卓(yingzhor@gmail.com)
 *
 */
public final class WebContextHolder {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(WebContextHolder.class);

    private static WebContextHolder INSTANCE = new WebContextHolder();

    public WebContextHolder get() {
        return INSTANCE;
    }

    private WebContextHolder() {
        super();
    }

    // --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    public HttpServletRequest getRequest() {
        ServletRequestAttributes attributes = (ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes();
        return attributes.getRequest();
    }

    public HttpSession getSession() {
        return getSession(true);
    }

    public HttpSession getSession(boolean create) {
        return getRequest().getSession(create);
    }

    public String getSessionId() {
        return getSession().getId();
    }

    public ServletContext getServletContext() {
        return getSession().getServletContext();    // servlet2.3
    }

    public Locale getLocale() {
        return RequestContextUtils.getLocale(getRequest());
    }

    public Theme getTheme() {
        return RequestContextUtils.getTheme(getRequest());
    }

    public ApplicationContext getApplicationContext() {
        return WebApplicationContextUtils.getWebApplicationContext(getServletContext());
    }

    public ApplicationEventPublisher getApplicationEventPublisher() {
        return (ApplicationEventPublisher) getApplicationContext();
    }

    public LocaleResolver getLocaleResolver() {
        return RequestContextUtils.getLocaleResolver(getRequest());
    }

    public ThemeResolver getThemeResolver() {
        return RequestContextUtils.getThemeResolver(getRequest());
    }

    public ResourceLoader getResourceLoader() {
        return (ResourceLoader) getApplicationContext();
    }

    public ResourcePatternResolver getResourcePatternResolver() {
        return (ResourcePatternResolver) getApplicationContext();
    }

    public MessageSource getMessageSource() {
        return (MessageSource) getApplicationContext();
    }

    public ConversionService getConversionService() {
        return getBeanFromApplicationContext(ConversionService.class);
    }

    public DataSource getDataSource() {
        return getBeanFromApplicationContext(DataSource.class);
    }

    public Collection<String> getActiveProfiles() {
        return Arrays.asList(getApplicationContext().getEnvironment().getActiveProfiles());
    }

    public ClassLoader getBeanClassLoader() {
        return ClassUtils.getDefaultClassLoader();
    }

    private <T> T getBeanFromApplicationContext(Class<T> requiredType) {
        try {
            return getApplicationContext().getBean(requiredType);
        } catch (NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException e) {
            LOGGER.error(e.getMessage(), e);
            throw e;
        } catch (NoSuchBeanDefinitionException e) {
            LOGGER.warn(e.getMessage());
            return null;
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 4):

Indeed you can access the information from the session even when the session is being destroyed on an HttpSessionLisener by doing:

```
public void sessionDestroyed(HttpSessionEvent hse) {
    SecurityContextImpl sci = (SecurityContextImpl) hse.getSession().getAttribute("SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT");
    // be sure to check is not null since for users who just get into the home page but never get authenticated it will be
    if (sci != null) {
        UserDetails cud = (UserDetails) sci.getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
        // do whatever you need here with the UserDetails
    }
 }
```

or you could also access the information anywhere you have the HttpSession object available like:

```
SecurityContextImpl sci = (SecurityContextImpl) session().getAttribute("SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT");
```

the last assuming you have something like:

```
HttpSession sesssion = ...; // can come from request.getSession(false);
```

Answer (score 4):

In my scenario, I've injected the HttpSession into the CustomAuthenticationProvider class
like this

```
public class CustomAuthenticationProvider extends  AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider{

    @Autowired 
    private HttpSession httpSession;

    @Override
    protected void additionalAuthenticationChecks(UserDetails userDetails, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken)
             throws AuthenticationException
    {
        System.out.println("Method invoked : additionalAuthenticationChecks isAuthenticated ? :"+usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.isAuthenticated());
    }

    @Override
    protected UserDetails retrieveUser(String username,UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authentication) throws AuthenticationException 
    {
        System.out.println("Method invoked : retrieveUser");
        //so far so good, i can authenticate user here, and throw exception 
if not authenticated!!
        //THIS IS WHERE I WANT TO ACCESS SESSION OBJECT
        httpSession.setAttribute("userObject", myUserObject);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I try with next code and work excellent

```
    import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
    import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
    import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

    /**
     * Created by jaime on 14/01/15.
     */

    @Controller
    public class obteinUserSession {
        @RequestMapping(value = "/loginds", method = RequestMethod.GET)
        public String UserSession(ModelMap modelMap) {
            Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
            String name = auth.getName();
            modelMap.addAttribute("username", name);
            return "hellos " + name;
        }
```

Comment: Please add an explanation with your code. Around here just throwing code or link at someone question isn't really an answer.

Answer (score 2):

If all that you need is details of User, for *Spring Version 4.x* you can use `@AuthenticationPrincipal` and `@EnableWebSecurity` tag provided by Spring as shown below.

Security Configuration Class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
   ...
}
```

Controller method:

```
@RequestMapping("/messages/inbox")
public ModelAndView findMessagesForUser(@AuthenticationPrincipal User user) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ServletRequestAttributes attr = (ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes();
attr.getSessionId();
```

Comment: Could you please add some additional information to your answer on how this solves the problem in comparison to the other existing answers?

Answer (score -1):

```
    String token = (String) pageContext.findAttribute("TOKEN");
    if (token.equals(null)) {
        System.out.println("No pasar");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Excelente llego");
    }
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is an [English Q&A only](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/13676/1416577). Non-English posts risk being [deleted](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers). Please [edit] and translate your answer to English.