# Store Axis raw XML request/response in session (to be used in JSP)

Tags: java, xml, wsdl, axis, wsdl2java

How, if possible, do I get the raw XML request/response that is invoked/retrieved by Axis in my application?

I'm using WSDL2Java that is included with Axis to generate the Java stubs.

**EDIT:**

What I currently have is an app that uses Axis to handle the remote API calls.

One of the requirement is to 'store' all the XML request/response from these calls in the session so that it will be available in the JSP (for debugging purposes). How can I achieve this?

I tried writing a custom handler that `extends BasicHandler` but in that handler, I still can't get the `HttpServletRequest`/`HttpServletResponse` pair from the `MessageContext`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I end up using the solution described in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1629211/how-do-i-get-the-session-object-in-spring/1629239#1629239)

Basically, I use it to get a hold of the HttpServletRequest and from there I set the proper item in the session.

Answer (score 14):

After a while searching its as simple as this:

//After your _call.invoke(...);

```
//Request
String request = _call.getMessageContext().getRequestMessage().getSOAPPart().getEnvelope().getBody().toString();

//Response
String response = _call.getMessageContext().getResponseMessage().getSOAPPart().getEnvelope().getBody().toString();
```

where _call is org.apache.axis.client.Call

Then you can save it in a file where you want...

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you write a server side soap handler, get hold of MessageContext and I believe there is a way to get hold of the payload from there. If you want to pass it to downstream then put it in thread local. See e.g. of handler [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/jdanforth/archive/2006/03/13/440116.aspx)

Comment: The application uses the API that is provided by a server. Why would I write a server side handler?