# How to put the HttpSession into an Aspect class using Spring?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, aspectj

I have an aspect class used to log the application, and I need information that's in the user session. Is there any way to provide the HttpSession for the aspect, or its attributes?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Sring MVC , the information is stored in the RequestContextHolder For Security you have the info in the SecurityContext .Check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1629211/how-do-i-get-the-session-object-in-spring) for more info .

Answer (score 1):

If you pass the HttpSession as a parameter it can be used by the advice:

```
@Before("args(httpSession,..)")
public void logHttpSession(HttpSession httpSession) {
    ...
}
```