# Why HttpSession is always new

Tags: java, spring, http, spring-mvc, web

My project is simple shop and im adding cart service to the shop. The algorithm is looking like this:
1) Creating ArrayList of product
2) Add that list to HttpSession as attribute
3) Next time algorithm ask is the cart inside httpSession artributes.

## SpringMVC

```
@Controller
public class CartController {

    @Autowired
    ShopServiceInterface shopServiceInterface;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/cart/add/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String addToCart(@PathVariable("id") Long id , ModelMap modelMap, HttpSession httpSession){
        if(httpSession.getAttribute("cart") == null) {
            List<CartItem> cart = new ArrayList<CartItem>();
            cart.add(new CartItem(shopServiceInterface.getProductById(id), 1));
            httpSession.setAttribute("cart", cart);
        } else {
            List<CartItem> cart = (List<CartItem>)httpSession.getAttribute("cart");
            cart.add(new CartItem(shopServiceInterface.getProductById(id),1));
            httpSession.setAttribute("cart", cart);
        }
        return "cart";
    }

}
```

Problem is when I try to add new product to cart it always makes a new `HttpSession`, and it always create new `ArrayList` cart. I saw, while debugging, that springMVC give me other `httpSession` object each time.

Comment: Scope? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10034993/spring-store-object-in-session

Comment: I don't see any problem here, I am curious how are you testing this? are you testing using a client which is capable of maintaining the session?

Comment: if you test this using curl and not passing the required headers each call will be each session anyway