# how add attribute to session without having model object in spring mvc?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have a class like:

```
@Controller(value = "services")
@RequestMapping("/")
@SessionAttributes({"SESSIONID"})
public class Services {

   @RequestMapping("/user/loginStatic")
   @ModelAttribute("SESSIONID")
   public LoginResponseBean loginStatic(String username){
       LoginResponseBean result = otherClass.login(username);
       retrun result;
   }
}
```

my problem: this code is cause to store "result" object in session but ***I want to store "result.getSessionId()" in session.***

I can not add "Model model" to input argument of "loginStatic" method because it whould change the method signitaure and I cann't do it now.
and also I can not get http session explicitely and set attribute in it (because of someother side effects).
how could I do that?
thanks..

Comment: NO, you have to add `ModelMap model` in input arguments of `loginStatic` and then `model.addAttribute("sessionId", result.getSeesionId())` would do your work. I don't think there is another way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `<mvc:interceptors/>` to register a custom [`HandlerInterceptor`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/HandlerInterceptor.html) which would apply to one, more or all controllers. For example, here is how to register an interceptor for all controllers:

```
<mvc:interceptors>
    <mvc:interceptor>
        <mvc:mapping path="/**"/>
        <bean class="a.b.c.MyHandlerInterceptorAdapter"/>
    </mvc:interceptor>
</mvc:interceptors>
```

Please also see [`mvc-config-interceptors`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-config-interceptors) and [`mvc-handlermapping-interceptor`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-handlermapping-interceptor) documentation for more details.

*Note: Spring 3.2 documentation linked, so you may want to change the release number in the URL to match the version of Spring you are using.*

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the accepted answer here:
[How do I get the session object in spring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1629211/how-do-i-get-the-session-object-in-spring)

You can get the session object as described there and add your attribute.

Comment: thanks for your advice; but it does not solve my problem becuase I should not get "session" explicitly (by using "(ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes()).

Instead I'm looking for another solution(if exist!!)