# access domain name from UserDetailsService

Tags: java, spring, authentication, spring-security

in Spring, I need to do additional verification in custom MyUserDetailsService when user login in, and I need the domain name where the user is login from.  any idea ?

Here is what worked out from me 
[How do I get the Session Object in Spring?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1629211/how-do-i-get-the-session-object-in-spring)

Comment: here is what worked for me
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1629211/how-do-i-get-the-session-object-in-spring

Answer (score 0):

Yon can inject (@Autowired) the HttpServletRequest into your MyUserDetailsService similar to the code below, I believe getRemoteHost() is what you are looking for?

```
@RestController
public class WebOneController {


    @Autowired
    private HttpServletRequest request;

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String hello() {
        return "host " + request.getRemoteHost();
    }
}
```

Comment: The class I am working with is from Spring Security http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/userdetails/UserDetailsService.html?is-external=true

Comment: How are you calling your "MyUserDetailsService" implementation of UserDetailsService?

Comment: I do not call it. Spring call that class as part of authentication. It is set as preAuthenticationProvider in Application-security.xml