# Sessions.getCurrent() yields null when authenticating by means of spring security

Tags: session, spring-security, nullpointerexception, zk

I've succeeded in integrating Spring Security into my zk web application. But I found some problem, Sessions.getCurrent() yields null on my custom authentication manager.

How I can solve this issue?

### CustomAuthenticationManager.java :

```
public class CustomAuthenticationManager implements AuthenticationManager {
    TparoperatorDAO oDao = new TparoperatorDAO();
    TparameterDAO oTparameterDao = new TparameterDAO();

    Session session;
    Transaction transaction;

    @Override
    public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {

        Tparoperator tparoperator = null;
        Authentication auth = null;
        String username = (String) authentication.getPrincipal();
        String password = (String) authentication.getCredentials();

        System.out.println("authenticate : " + username);

        if (username.isEmpty() || password.isEmpty()) {
            throw new BadCredentialsException("Username atau password tidak boleh kosong!");
        }

        try {
            session = StoreHibernateUtil.openSession();
            tparoperator = oDao.login(session, username);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            throw new BadCredentialsException("Invalid username/password");
        }

        if (tparoperator == null) {
            throw new BadCredentialsException("User tidak ditemukan");
        } else if (Helper.ToString(tparoperator.getStatususer()).equals(SysUtils.STATUS_WAIT_NOT_ACTIVE)) {
            throw new BadCredentialsException("User tidak aktif");
        } else if (tparoperator.getStatuslogin().equals("1")) {
            throw new BadCredentialsException("User sedang dipakai");
        }

        //FIXME: uncomment this connect LDAP
        //this.ldapAuthentication(authentication);

        try {
            auth = this.setAuthorities(authentication, tparoperator, session);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            throw new BadCredentialsException("Authentication Error");
        }

        return auth;
    }

    public Authentication setAuthorities(Authentication authentication, Tparoperator p, Session session) throws Exception {
        String sessionId = "";

        org.zkoss.zk.ui.Session zkSession = Sessions.getCurrent();
        Object mySession = Sessions.getCurrent();
        if (mySession != null) {
            mySession = ((org.zkoss.zk.ui.Session) mySession).getNativeSession();
        }

        if (mySession != null) {
            HttpSession httpsession = (HttpSession) mySession;
            sessionId = httpsession.getId();
        }

        System.out.println("SESSION ID : " + sessionId);
        System.out.println("SESSION : " + zkSession);

        p.setSessionid(sessionId);
        p.setStatuslogin("1");

        ArrayList<GrantedAuthority> grantedAuthorities = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>();
        grantedAuthorities.add(new GrantedAuthorityImpl("ROLE_USER"));
        UserUtils userUtils = this.buildAccessMenu(p, authentication.getPrincipal().toString(), authentication.getCredentials().toString(), sessionId, grantedAuthorities);
        zkSession.setAttribute("userUtils", userUtils);

        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken auth = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(p, authentication.getCredentials(), grantedAuthorities);
        UserDetailsImpl details = new UserDetailsImpl(p);
        details.setAuthorities(grantedAuthorities);
        auth.setDetails(details);

        //UPDATE ONLINE
        transaction = session.beginTransaction();
        oDao.save(session, p);
        transaction.commit();

        return auth;
    }
}
```

### web.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
         xmlns:web="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd
         http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
         version="2.4">

    <display-name>cms</display-name>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            /WEB-INF/applicationContext-security.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.security.web.session.HttpSessionEventPublisher</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

<!-- omit code for abbreviate -->

    </web-app>
```

### applicationContext-security.xml :

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.0.3.xsd
       ">


    <security:http entry-point-ref="myAuthenticationEntryPoint" create-session="always">
        <security:session-management>
            <security:concurrency-control expired-url="/logout.zul" max-sessions="1"
                                          error-if-maximum-exceeded="true"></security:concurrency-control>
        </security:session-management>
        <security:custom-filter position="FORM_LOGIN_FILTER" ref="customizedFormLoginFilter"/>

        <!-- anonymous pages -->
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/zkau/**" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY"/>
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/login.zul" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY"/>
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/index.zul" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY"/>

        <security:intercept-url pattern="/templates/**" filters="none"/>
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/css/**" filters="none"/>
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/js/**" filters="none"/>
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/images/**" filters="none"/>

        <!-- secure pages -->
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="ROLE_USER"/>
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/logout.zul" access="ROLE_USER"/>

        <security:logout logout-success-url="/login.zul"/>
        <security:anonymous username="guest" granted-authority="ROLE_ANONYMOUS"/>

    </security:http>

    <bean id="myAuthenticationEntryPoint" class="com.sdd.cms.security.CustomAuthenticationEntryPoint">
        <property name="loginFormUrl" value="/login.zul"/>
    </bean>

    <security:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager"/>

    <bean id="customizedFormLoginFilter" class="com.sdd.cms.security.CustomAuthenticationFilter">
        <property name="filterProcessesUrl" value="/j_spring_security_check"/>
        <property name="authenticationSuccessHandler" ref="myAuthSuccessHandler"/>
        <property name="authenticationFailureHandler" ref="myAuthFailureHandler"/>
        <property name="authenticationManager" ref="myAuthenticationManager"/>
        <property name="allowSessionCreation" value="true"/>
    </bean>


    <bean id="myAuthSuccessHandler"
          class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler">
        <property name="defaultTargetUrl" value="/content/index.zul"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="myAuthFailureHandler" class="com.sdd.cms.security.MyAuthenticationFailuerHandler">
        <property name="defaultFailureUrl" value="/login.zul?error=true"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="myAuthenticationManager" class="com.sdd.cms.security.CustomAuthenticationManager"/>

    <bean id="loggerListener" class="org.springframework.security.access.event.LoggerListener"/>

</beans>
```

get session :

```
String sessionId = "";

            org.zkoss.zk.ui.Session zkSession = Sessions.getCurrent();
            Object mySession = Sessions.getCurrent();
            if (mySession != null) {
                mySession = ((org.zkoss.zk.ui.Session) mySession).getNativeSession();
            }

            if (mySession != null) {
                HttpSession httpsession = (HttpSession) mySession;
                sessionId = httpsession.getId();
            }

            System.out.println("SESSION ID : " + sessionId);
            System.out.println("SESSION : " + zkSession);
```

### result :

```
java.lang.NullPointerException 
SESSION ID :
SESSION : null
```

Please help me,

Regards,
Rayhan

Comment: you don't need to put the credentials in ZK session, look at the answer here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1629211/how-do-i-get-the-session-object-in-spring